# How to highlight the clicked (by mouse) element of a delegate w.r.t FolderListModel?

Tags: qml, qtquick2

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.0

Item
{
    Component {
        id: highlight
        Rectangle {
            id: rooot
            width: 180; height: 20
            color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "black" : "red"; radius: 5

            y: list.currentItem.y
            Behavior on y {
                SpringAnimation {
                    spring: 3
                    damping: 0.2
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        width: 480; height: 400
        model: folderModel
        delegate: Text { id: h; text: fileName }

        highlight: highlight
        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false

        focus: true
    }

    FolderListModel
    {
        id: folderModel
        folder:      "/home/anisha/"
        nameFilters: ["*"]
    }
}
```

This works only when I use keyboard. How to make it work on mouse clicks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QML Listview selected item highlight on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400002/qml-listview-selected-item-highlight-on-click)

Comment: You need to insert `MouseArea` inside your delegate and provide next code: `MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: list.currentIndex = index }`

Comment: @troyane thanks, I found that after posting this question.

Comment: better to do it in reverse order :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To react on mouse events you need to place `MouseArea` item.

In the sample below (being an expanded version of the code you provided) I have added a `MouseArea` to the delegate item that upon being clicked sets the `ListView`'s `currentIndex` to the delegate's `index` (a special property visible in the `ListView`'s delegate).

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.0

Item
{
    Component {
        id: highlight
        Rectangle {
            id: rooot
            width: 180; height: 20
            color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "black" : "red"; radius: 5

            y: list.currentItem.y
            Behavior on y {
                SpringAnimation {
                    spring: 3
                    damping: 0.2
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        width: 480; height: 400
        model: folderModel
        delegate:
        Text {
            id: h;
            text: fileName

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: list.currentIndex = index
            }
        }

        highlight: highlight
        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false

        focus: true
    }

    FolderListModel
    {
        id: folderModel
        folder:      "/home/anisha/"
        nameFilters: ["*"]
    }
}
```

As an alternative approach you might try placing a single `MouseArea` filling the whole `ListView` and use `ListView`'s `indexAt(int x, int y)` method to check which delegate was clicked. However, you would need to care about more edge-conditions in such case.